# Kendo UI - how to implement Error Handling on WEB API, non MVC using Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

My Scenario is I created a Web API that returns an Active Directory Object.

I have this WEB API function create Active Directory User and creates a user that returns Active Directory Object that contains `First Name , Last Name, Email, UserName, Etc.`.. What If it got an error how would I handle this?

I'm using Kendo Grid InLine Edit http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html
I want to show the error message as a pop up window

How would I do that???

Options

1. try catch the error and put in the Active Directory Object as
   Exception???

   - How can I capture this is Kendo UI?
2. Throw the response and get the error message and show it in the Kendo Grid

   //HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                               //{
                               //    Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No User with ID = {0}.{1}", businessObject.UserName, ex.InnerException.ToString() )),
                               //    ReasonPhrase = "CustomerID Not Found in Database!"
                               //};
                               //throw new HttpResponseException(msg);

OR

```
  //var message = string.Format("Error Message: {0}", taskCreateADUser.ADExceptionDescription);
                //throw new HttpResponseException(
                //    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, message));
```

Thanks,
MarcLevin

Answer (score 3):

Whenever KendoUI binds via Ajax it relies on serialized version of ModelState sent in json response. Essentially if ModelState is not valid, the json response returned to the widget (grid in this case) will contain something like this:

```
{
  "Errors":{
     "PropA":{
        "errors":[
           "Error1",
    "Error2"
        ]
     },
     "PropB":{
        "errors":[
           "FUBAR"
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

Essentially your WebAPI will need to return similar data structure if you want the grid to respond to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is regarding your Option 2. You would need to apply the following correctly to your specific scenario. This is just a sample of a really simple parse of the response and displaying an alert if an error is detected. This sample expects a JSON object containing an array of Items. You could definitely apply more advanced handling once you have the basic idea down.

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    schema: {
                        data: function(data) {
                            if (data.Items[0].substring(0,37) == "allmyerrormessagesstartwiththisphrase"){
                            alert(data.Items[0];
                            } else {
                                return data.Items;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://myurl.com/something/"
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```